# Get other different id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple mysql query:

```
SELECT    U.id FROM
users U
    INNER JOIN friends F
        ON ( U.id = F.id_exp AND F.id_des = :id_exp )
        OR ( U.id = F.id_des AND F.id_exp = :id_exp ) WHERE
U.id <> :id_des
AND F.active = 1
```

I wish that by calling this request again, that It does not return the id that It has already previously returned.

I hope you understand me.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to iterate, selecting random IDs from those tables each time?

Comment: "iterate" I think.

Comment: I think is more efficient to select a set of possibles IDs and then in your specific language shuffle them in a random way. Specially if you're going to do several select queries (That's why i wrote "iterate", i was thinking doing that with a programming lang)

Answer (score 1):

You must give `RAND` a seed number in order to always get the same order. This can be any number, e.g. 1:

```
...
ORDER BY RAND(1)
LIMIT @offset, 1;
```

Comment: I have tried that:
ORDER BY RAND(1)
LIMIT @offset, 1                                                                                         
But It gives a FATAL ERROR.

Comment: "FATAL ERROR" is a strange error message. `@offset` is a variable. You must define it or replace it with a value, e.g. `LIMIT 99, 1` when you are asking for the hundredth ID.